# When should I use `require` a package which is `autoload`?

Tags: emacs, require, autoload, evil-mode

For example, [evil is autoload](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/blob/49ebf2dce325bc7fe0941dc4112226c291ff9670/evil-core.el#L178),

Some blogs/threads will use

```
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)
```

to enable evil mode.

AFAIK, Elisp is lisp2 and `evil-mode` is also a function, so doesn't need `setq`.

```
(defadvice evil-mode (after start-evil activate)
  "Enable Evil in Fundamental mode."
  (if evil-mode
      (progn
        (when (eq (default-value 'major-mode) 'fundamental-mode)
          ;; changed back by `evil-local-mode'
          (setq-default major-mode 'turn-on-evil-mode))
        (ad-enable-regexp "^evil")
        (ad-activate-regexp "^evil")
        (with-no-warnings (evil-esc-mode 1)))
    (when (eq (default-value 'major-mode) 'turn-on-evil-mode)
      (setq-default major-mode 'fundamental-mode))
    (ad-disable-regexp "^evil")
    (ad-update-regexp "^evil")
    (with-no-warnings (evil-esc-mode -1))))
```

But， because of `autoload`,

```
(evil-mode 1)
```

Without `require`, it also works fine(at least for me)

(If anywhere below is wrong, please correct me, thx)

My question is when must I use `require` if the required package is autoloaded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct -- if an `autoload` declaration for `evil-mode` has been evaluated, then there is no need to `(require 'evil)` prior to `(evil-mode 1)`

Individual users may or may not need to `(require 'evil)` though.  It's a question of how the library has been installed.  On its own an `;;;###autoload` cookie does nothing; but if you installed `evil` using package.el, then they will have been parsed and turned into a file of `autoload` declarations, which Emacs will load when packages are initialised.

If you install a library without using a package manager, then you may need to `require` it, or else write your own `autoload` declaration for the functions you might be calling.